# I have more than one copy of the same app installed. How do I remove one specifically?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, snap, software-uninstall

Ubuntu 20.04. Today I was not able to get on Slack due to it's version reaching it's end of life.

I could not find a way to unistall it via command line due to the slack package not being found, nor via the Ubuntu Software app as it was simply not there.

I went on and ran `sudo snap install slack`, which installed the latest stable version of it and to which I could log back in.

But now I have two different Slack apps installed. I suppose I must of have installed the first one in a different way, as the new version did not replace the old one as I can run both simultaneously (one of course is the non working version). Now I don't know which is which nor how to unistall the one that reached it's end of life.

I suppose this can happen again with any app, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We need to know how you originally installed the version you want to remove.

Comment: did you install it as a .deb package? maybe try `sudo apt remove slack-desktop` - and `whereis slack` or `whereis slack-desktop` might provide some hints

Answer (score 0):

This should clear it up. Right now there are three slack snap packages:

```
$ snap search slack | egrep "^slack"
slack                          4.28.171             slack**             -      Team communication for the 21st century.
slack-term                     0.5.0                snapcrafters        -      Slack client for your terminal
slack-git-compare              0.1.1                maxime-visonneau    -      Compare git references within Slack
```

And one apt package:

```
$ apt list slack
Listing... Done
slack/focal,focal,now 1:0.15.2-9 all
```

This looks for the other "slack-" snap packages, removes them, then removes the slack package that may or may not be installed with apt:

```
snap find slack | egrep "^slack-" | awk '{print $1}' | 
xargs sudo snap remove ;
dpkg -l | grep slack 1&>/dev/null && sudo apt purge slack -qqy 2&> /dev/null || 
echo -e "\n\n\nNot/no longer installed with apt\n\n"; 
a=$(egrep "^slack " <(snap list slack)) ;
if echo "$a" &>/dev/null; then echo "$a" |
awk '{print "\n\nSlack Installed via snap: "$1,$2"\n\n"}';
else echo "Looks like it is not installed via snap\n\n"; fi ; echo done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command to see if it helps.

```
$ locate slack.desktop

/home/username/.var/app/com.slack.Slack/config/autostart/slack.desktop
/var/lib/flatpak/app/com.slack.Slack/x86_64/stable/b95d24a8a354db07b95b065b3e57e9442c9fbaf851a49cbe6e7b1aa0afcab591/files/extra/share/applications/slack.desktop
```

If you see Flatpak then it is installed using Flatpak, then uninstall it using

```
flatpak uninstall com.slack.Slack
```